# Android sip client testing without having two android phones

Tags: android, sip

Is there any technique to verify one's sip client in android is Ok for two devices, without having to test on two android devices. Because i don't have two android phones?

Answer (score 0):

Use a PC [softphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softphone). I used [X-Lite](http://www.counterpath.com/x-lite.html) when I had to test my mobile app and it worked well.